# How to create a windows 10 user with very specific access right?

Tags: windows-10, permissions

So I want the user to be able to operate only with one specific folder *Z* (maybe it can list other directories, but newer read or write anything). In that folder it can only read+write file *X*, and execute only file *Y*. Been struggling to figure this out. As by default new user has access to everything :/

Comment: What you want is fundamentally impossible on Windows.  A Windows user must have access to their own profile directory.  If you were to deny write permissions to their own user profile, the user wouldn't be able to use that directory, and a temporary one would be created each time the user were to log into their account.  You can certainly deny write permissions to a folder and allow a user explicit permissions to a single file provided the file does not inherit the permissions of the folder.

Comment: Ok, so profile directory could be an exception?

Comment: It would also include (Program Files, AppData, ect.) basically any default directory that exists.  How you handle non-default directories is entirely customizable.

Comment: Uff :/ . So will need some Unix system

Comment: Your approach to permissions is backwards from how every operating system I am aware of works.  No, Unix is no different.. even more limited actually (even though I love it).. Unix has ONE USER, and ONE GROUP that can own/access files, that's IT.. On Unix I need to be creative to work things into a group.  NTFS/ACLs allow MUCH more finite control.

Comment: @JohnT - I have no idea, what you actually want is confusing, but your description isn't possible on Windows, Linux, nor Unix.